# ASTParser and dependency between methods

Tags: java, tree, dependencies, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using `ASTParser` to parse Java source code in a project.  I managed to get the name and the return type of all the methods in the different classes of my Java project.  I'm now wondering if it's possible to have the dependencies between the methods in `main`.
In fact I haven't read all the documentation for this class which is a bit complicated. Do you know if it's possible to have an idea about the interconnectedness of the methods in the main program?  If it's not possible is there another API that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is known to be very difficult because of the difficulty of determining which specific methods will get called, since Java allows for overriding of most methods.  In the worst case, this is undecidable, and so the best you're going to be able to get is a conservative approximation.  Accordingly, there is no one good algorithm for solving this problem, though many research papers have tried to answer the question to some degree.

The [BDDBDDB framework](http://suif.stanford.edu/~jwhaley/papers/pods05.pdf) can be used to perform this sort of analysis, and were able to get a very accurate call graph for the program.  However, this would require you to learn to use a new framework instead of the `ASTParser` you're using now.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.4066&rep=rep1&type=pdf) also claims to have developed a good type analysis for Java that allows for static method resolution.  It works by compiling the Java code into its own intermediate language, though, and would probably not work with `ASTParser`.